# How to reuse the result from spark stream?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

How can we use the value inside the map, it seems the values not being filled.

```
  val goalScore = rawScore.transform(rdd=>{
        val minMax = rdd.flatMap(x=>{
          x.behaviorProfileType match {
            case Some("mapper") => Some((x.sourceType, x.targetType, "mapper"), x)          
            case Some("non-mappe") => Some((x.sourceType, x.targetType, "non-mapper"), x)
            case _ => None     
          }
        })
        .reduceByKey(reduceMinMax(_, _))
        .collectAsMap()

        rdd.map(x => (populateMinMaxWindowGoalScore(x, minMax)))
      })
```

Why minMax is always empty inside populateMinMaxWindowGoalScore function? rawScore is a DStream.

Comment: could you extend your code? also how do you debug that minmax is empty? what is the input? please provide more details